# Matching two sets of data for highlighting

Tags: google-sheets

I have two positive values in columns A1:B1, and a small table
on D1:H2 on the same spreadsheet. I'd like to use a formula to conditionally
highlight the values of A1:B1 on the table (if they're present).
I tried to do this using match, and hlookup, but I couldn't make it work.
I'd be glad if you could give me a little help.

sample data:

```
A : B       D   E   F   G   H 
1   5       1   3   5   7   9
            2   4   6   8   10
```

So the result'd be like this with conditional formatting:

[image]

Comment: Show your formula.

Comment: here one of the formulas i tried which didn't work. =MATCH(HLOOKUP(a$1,$A$1:$b$1,0,0),$d$1:$h$2,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the conditional format custom formula to this:

```
=MATCH(D1,$A$1:$B$1,0)
```

(assuming the table you're formatting starts at cell D1). There's no need for `HLOOKUP`.

In a conditional format custom formula, a relative cell reference (no `$` signs) will be replaced for each cell in the formatted range.  So the `D1` here basically means "the current cell."

We're trying to match the current cell to *any* cell in the lookup table, so we just reference the whole range of the lookup table (`$A$1:$B:$1`). The absolute reference (`$`'s) makes it so that this reference is always the same, even as the conditional format rule iterates over the range of formatted cells.